# Possible to train Tensorflow Inception V3 models with images greater than 299x299?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to train a Tensorflow Inception V3 model with an image size greater than size 299x299? Seems that the Inception V3 CNN is designed for this image size only.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not include the fully connected (Dense) layers at the top, it should be fine to use a different image size.
You can do that by adding this argument while loading the model
 `base_model = InceptionV3(weights=weights, include_top=False)`

The convolutional layer weights should be independent of the image size in general and hence you can use those weights. The FC layer of the pre-trained network with n fully connected nodes would have a weight matrix of size`[m X n]`. This layer will expect the input to that layer to be of size `m`. However, due to the change in image size, you will end up with a different value for `m` when you feed the image from the new dataset(convolution filter convolving on a different image size).

After adding new dense layers, you can fine-tune the network to train on the top layers alone (keeping the weights of the conv-blocks below it fixed).

Comment: I'm not using keras but Tensorflow with slim. I could look at the code in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/applications/inception_v3.py and see if I can replicate it in slim